# What happens when I run java -jar from command line

Tags: java

I want to understand what happens when I run:

```
java -jar some.jar
```

from command line.

I know that in order to launch a java program, it must contain `main()` method so should I assume that the `jar` file I am running has such `main()` method in one of its classes and just runs it by default? In such case, what if there is more than one class that has `main()` method as I don't believe there are any restrictions on how many classes can have `main()` methods.

Comment: Look into configuring the JAR manifest file, in which you can specify a specific class as an entry point.

Comment: Have a look at [Working with Manifest Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html), in particular [Setting an Application's Entry Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html